# Sorting highest value of another query

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, ranking

to get the statistic value of a player in the last month I use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE player='player1' AND statistic=0 AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Now I want the Top 10 players with the highest value.
Example:
player1 has the value 40 (from the query above)
player2 has the value 78 (from the query above)
player3 has the value 21 (from the query above)

Now the ranking must be:

1. player2
2. player1
3. player3

But how can I sort the ranking? Because I need the value of the query above?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking, p.*
FROM (SELECT player, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM test
      WHERE statistic=0 AND time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      GROUP BY player
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
     ) p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Can you show me how I get the rank of a player? Example: player1

Comment: @AlexK. . . .If using this as a subquery doesn't get what you want, ask another question.